# Spark Statistical Functions Python

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark

I asked a question for statistical functions and got an answer but I am looking at another way to do it:

What I find weird is:
This works:

```
myData = dataSplit.map(lambda arr: (arr[1]))
myData2 = myData.map(lambda line: line.split(',')).map(lambda fields: ("Column", float(fields[0]))).groupByKey()
stats[1] = myData2.map(lambda (Column, values): (min(values))).collect()
```

But when I add this function:

```
stats[4] = myData2.map(lambda (Column, values): (values)).variance()
```

It fails.

So I put some print:

```
myData = dataSplit.map(lambda arr: (arr[1]))
print myData.collect()
myData2 = myData.map(lambda line: line.split(',')).map(lambda fields: ("Column", float(fields[0]))).groupByKey()
print myData2.map(lambda (Column, values): (values)).collect()
```

Printing myData:

```
[u'18964', u'18951', u'18950', u'18949', u'18960', u'18958', u'18956', u'19056', u'18948', u'18969', u'18961', u'18959', u'18957', u'18968', u'18966', u'18967', u'18971', u'18972', u'18353', u'18114', u'18349', u'18348', u'18347', u'18346', u'19053', u'19052', u'18305', u'18306', u'18318', u’18317']
```

Printing myData2:

```
[<pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x7f3f7d3e0710>]
```

Answer (score -1):

solved

```
 print  myData.map(lambda line: line.split(',')).map(lambda fields: ("Column", float(fields[0]))).map(lambda (column, value) : (value)).stdev()
```